# What is the math behind shapeburst fill?

Tags: polygon, fill

I'm talking about this: https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/gradient/

I wanted to understand how it calculates the distance to the closest edge.

Comment: You mean this post, correct? http://nyalldawson.net/2014/06/shapeburst-fill-styles-in-qgis-2-4/

Comment: The answer must be somewhere in the source code https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aqgis%2FQGIS+shapeburst&type=code&p=1.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/symbology/qgsfillsymbollayer.cpp#L1499

Comment: Thanks! @user2856